# Can i have 2 objects in the same array space

Tags: java, arrays

So the aim is to create a pacman game in java console.
I have a class called Labyrinth used to initialise a 2d Object array based on an int array. Since a square in Pacman can either be a moveable space or a wall, i instanciate either a space or a wall.

```
public Labyrinth() {

    tab2 = new Object[25][23]; // On part du principe que la taille du labyrinth ne change pas

    for (int ligne = 0; ligne < tab.length; ++ligne) {
        for (int colonne = 0; colonne < tab[ligne].length; ++colonne) {
            int value = tab[ligne][colonne];
            Position p = new Position(ligne, colonne);
            switch (value) {
                case 0:
                    s = new Space(value, p);
                    tab2[ligne][colonne] = s;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    w = new Wall(p);
                    tab2[ligne][colonne] = w;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    s = new Space(value, p);
                    tab2[ligne][colonne] = s;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    s = new Space(value, p);
                    tab2[ligne][colonne] = s;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    s = new Space(value, p);
                    tab2[ligne][colonne] = s;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    s = new Space(value, p);
                    tab2[ligne][colonne] = s;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    s = new Space(value, p);
                    tab2[ligne][colonne] = s;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

"tab" is the int array and "tab2" is the object array.
The "value" parameter is an int based on the int array used to create the 2d object array.
Is it possible to instantiate Pacman, ghosts and various foods like so:

```
public class Space{
 Ghost g;
 Pacman pac;
 Food f;

 public Space(int value, Position p) {

    super(p);
    switch (value) {            
        case 2:
            pac = new Pacman(p);
            break;
        case 3:
            g = new Ghost(p);
            break;
        case 4:
            f = new Gum(p);
            break;
        case 5:
            f = new Fruit(p);
            break;
        case 6:
            f = new Shroom(p);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }       
}
```

This means that i have a space object and a food, pacman or ghost obeject on the same array"coordinate".

Edit: the aim here is to move Pacman from 1 "space"object to another
Edit2: didn't realize i put 2 times the same code

Comment: Do you mean `GameObject[] gos`?

Comment: No clue what that is.

Comment: I'm not clear how your main description relates to your "Edit".

Comment: I probably explained it very badly. I have a 2d array of either "Wall" or "(movable) Space". Inside a space, there can be a pacman. How can i move Pacman from 1 space to another.

Comment: You mean *every* array element is currently a space or wall. Now, you need to have more than one game object in a single array space and that space may potentially have an unknown number objects there; is that right? Moving the pacman around is simple, you just put it at the location in the 2d array where it belongs.

Comment: Yes. But the problem is taht from the Labyrinth class, i cannot acces the instance of pacman. I get a nullpointer error.

Comment: Well, that's unrelated to what it seems like you're actually asking. Where do you set or instantiate the `pacman`?

Comment: In Space. Forgot to paste the correct code before.

Answer (score 0):

> Edit: the aim here is to move Pacman from 1 "space"object to another

Then, why don't you want to model it that way?

Let your `Space` class accept some "content":

```
enum SpaceContent{
  EMPTY,FOOD,GHOST,PAC_MAN
}

class Space {
   private SpaceContent content = SpaceContent.EMPTY;

   public void setContent(SpaceContent content){
    this.content = content;
   }
}
```

When doing so you array elements are all of the same type `Space`

This might look like only a little advantage over having the 2dim-array being of type  `SpaceContent` directly, but look at this:

```
enum Direction {
 NORTH,EAST,SOUTH,WEST
}

class Space {
  private SpaceContent content = SpaceContent.EMPTY;
  private Map<Direction,Space> neigbours = new HasMap<>();
  // ...
  public void setNeigbour(Direction direction, Space space){
    neigbours.put(direction,space);
  }

  boolean isSpace(){
     return true;
  } 

  public boolean moveTo(Direction direction){
    if(!neigbours.containsKey(direction))
       return false; // cannot move out of the field. 

    Space target = neigbours.get(direction);
    if(!target.isSpace())
        return false; // cannot move into a wall

    target.setContent(content);
    content = SpaceContent.EMPTY;
  }
}

class Wall extends Space{
   @override 
   boolean isSpace(){
     return false;
  }        
}
```

and at the method that moves your figures:

```
  class Ghost{
    private Direction lastDirection;
    private int x,y;
    // getters and setters
    public void movedTo(Direction newDirection){
       lastDirection = newDirection;
       x= newDirection.nextX(x); // we have to enhance the enum for this
       y= newDirection.nextY(y); 
    }
  }
  List<Ghost> ghosts = new ArrayList<>(); // filled with ghosts elsewhere.
  // tab2 is an array of `Space`
  void moveGhosts(){
    for(Ghost ghost : ghosts){
       Direction direction = ghost.getLastDirection();
       Space currentField = 
      while(!tab2[ghost.getX()][ghost.getY()].moveTo(direction)){
         direction = turnRight(direction);
      }
      ghost.moveTo(direction);
    }

    private void turnRight(Direction direction){
       return  Direction.values()[direction.ordinal()+1% Direction.values().length];
    }
}
```